# What God does Captain America believe in?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

In the Avengers movie, there is a scene inside a jet, where Captain America tells that "there is only one God", to Black Widow.

The exact dialogue goes like this:

> Black Widow: These guys come from legend. They're basically gods.
>
> Captain America: There's only one God, ma'am, and I'm pretty sure he
>   doesn't dress like that.

**So, what God does Captain America believe in?**

Also, is Captain America a Christian, like the regular American?

Comment: Thanos. haha j/k

Comment: "My god carries a hammer." -- Nick Fury

Comment: (So maybe he's a carpenter?)

Comment: What is "the regular American"?

Comment: @mattdm Sorry for putting it vaguely.  I meant, the majority of Americans at his time :)

Comment: Related: [What is Captain America's religion?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/18103/2865) on [scifi.se]

Comment: I wonder how Rogers reconciles his version of God with meeting a literal God in the form of Thor...

Comment: @JonathanReez - Being supernaturally tough and talented in a world full of such people is still a pretty big step down from being Omnipotent, Omniscient, and Omnipresent.

Comment: @T.E.D. Judging by the comics, Thanos with the Infinity Gauntlet will have similar power in Avengers: Infinity War.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

In the MCU, I don't think Steve Rogers has ever explicitly declared his religion. The circumstantial evidence would suggest he's Christian or Jewish, with (IMO) the more likely case being Christian.

- The fact that he claims there is only one God indicates that he's monotheistic. That *most likely* means Jewish, Christian, or Muslim.
- He grew up in New York in the 1920s. By far the vast majority of Americans in the 20s and 30s were Protestant Christians, but there was also a rapidly growing Jewish community in New York.
- He's clearly of Western European descent (e.g. he's "white"). In the 20's and 30's, most Muslims in the US were immigrants from the Middle East.
- His surname is Rogers; this is primarily an English/Irish/Scottish surname, where again the dominant religion is Christianity.

As a final point, in the source comics, he's definitely Irish Catholic. He has discussed his upbringing as the son of an Irish Catholic family and how his family's faith made an impression on him. While the MCU Steve Rogers hasn't made the same claim (and is unlikely to do so explicity, I suspect) that would fit well with the rest of his character.

Comment: +1: He's also "Captain **America**" ...& when first drawn, that would be the only "acceptable" religion to have [this is not 'my opinion on theology' but a reference to the time the character was 'born in', which the movies have to echo to some extent.] - it also makes his "global statement of truth" quite funny in the modern age & gives away his anachronistic belief-set on all things, not just religion.

Comment: He has always struck me as being hella WASPy, so it's interesting that he's Catholic in the comics! I figured that would be considered to un-American.

Comment: Note that being a Catholic in the 1920's actually would have made him something of a [reviled minority at the time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Catholicism_in_the_United_States#1920s), including being a target of the KKK in places where they were active. His creators at Marvel were **not unaware of this**. A point was being made here.

Comment: Even in the comics, he hasn't explicitly said that *he* is Irish Catholic, despite having an Irish Catholic family, has he? The discussion [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/18103/32855) seems inconclusive.

Comment: Extended discussion under this post about entirely unrelated issues of ethnic-relgious dichotomies or what exactly the preactice of writing "g-d" instead of "god" implies or who does so have been cleansed from this comment thread. If you feel the need to discuss issues like that, take it somewhere else. Thank you.

Comment: He's protestant, anyway.
http://www.adherents.com/lit/comics/CaptainAmerica.html

Answer (score 1):

As the internet is full of in-depth writings on just about any subject you can name, you should know that there is a [definitive guide to the religious affiliations of super heroes](http://www.adherents.com/lit/comics/comic_book_religion.html). Which names Captain America as Protetsant (a rather large branch of Christianity).

He's actually got [his own page](http://www.adherents.com/lit/comics/CaptainAmerica.html) which goes into depth on how this can be seen in various comic books, and the effect it has on his character development.

Comment: I think this question is about the MCU cap, as the OP uses movie quotes and the question is tagged `marvel-cinematic-universe`

Comment: @JaccoAmersfoort as far as I know, the films haven't done anything to counteract that.